# KivyMD Using MDScreen?

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to kivy and I feel this might be a simple syntax error. I am trying to build the UI for my kivy program, I have found that when I use  `MDApp` my `theme_cls` has no attribute. Whereas, when I use `MDScreen` everything works perfectly.

How do I fix this whilst using MDScreen so I am able to use it as a screen.

This is my code.

```
class home(MDScreen):
     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(home, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(self.build())   

     def build(self):

        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Orange'
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue="A700"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style="Dark"
        screen  = Screen()
        monologue = MDRaisedButton(text="Monologue",
                pos_hint={"center_x": 0.2, "center_y": 0.3},
                md_bg_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                size_hint = (0.2,0.2)
        )
        logout = MDRaisedButton(text="Logout",
                pos_hint={"center_x": 0.1, "center_y": 0.9},
                md_bg_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                size_hint = (0.01,0.01))
       # self.logout.bind(on_press=self.build)
        duologue = MDRaisedButton(text="Duologue",
                    pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.3},
                md_bg_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                size_hint = (0.2,0.2))
        stats = MDRaisedButton(text="Stats",
                    pos_hint={"center_x": 0.8, "center_y": 0.3},
                    size_hint = (0.2,0.2),
                md_bg_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                )
        screen.add_widget(logout)
        screen.add_widget(monologue)
        screen.add_widget(duologue)
        screen.add_widget(stats)

        return screen
```

I've tried implementing another class as a screen and returning my home class but it did not solve the error.